# Como funciona o WebService SOAP/Rest com JAX-WS?

Tags: java, web-service, java-ee, soap, jax-ws

Passei um dia inteiro estudando e finalmente consegui realizar a autenticação com WebService SOAP usando JAX-WS, utilizando cliente gerado pelo Eclipse.

Ao agregar a senha e password à mensagem SOAP, como é feito isso? Ele coloca codificado?

Codigo do cliente:

```
RealizarBuscaSOAPService servico_ = servico.getRealizarBuscaSOAPServicePort();
Stub stub = (Stub) servico_;
stub._setProperty(Stub.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "usuario");
stub._setProperty(Stub.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "senha");
```

Código do serviço:

```
    @Resource
WebServiceContext webServiceContext;

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
private boolean validaClient(){
    MessageContext mc = webServiceContext.getMessageContext();
    Map http_headers = (Map) mc.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);
    System.out.println(http_headers);

    String username = null;
    String password = null;

    List t = (List)http_headers.get("Authorization");
    if(t == null || t.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Auth failed");
    }

    String encodedText = ((String) t.get(0)).substring(5);
    System.out.println("ENCODED TEXT:"+encodedText);


    byte[] buf = null;
    try {
        buf = Base64.decode(encodedText.getBytes());
    } catch (Base64DecodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String credentials = new String(buf);
    System.out.println("decoded text: "+credentials);

    int p = credentials.indexOf(":");

    if(p > -1){
        username = credentials.substring(0,p);
        password = credentials.substring(p+1);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in decoding");
    }

    return autentica(username, password);
}
```

Por que essa decodificação Base64? Quando a senha e password são colocadas no cabeçalho, eles são codificados usando base 64?? O serviço e o cliente trocam alguma chave?

A única autenticação que existe em REST seria em nível HTTP e direto na URL do serviço com alguma chave ou usuário e senha direto no URL do serviço?

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a codificação em Base64: ela é necessárias pois é uma forma de garantir que o conteúdo do login e senha do usuário não sofram alterações durante as transferências cliente-servidor. É constituído por 64 caracteres (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `/` e `+`, além do sufixo `=`)

Ela é utilizada no protocolo `HTTP` para autenticação, que você está utilizando em:

```
List t = (List)http_headers.get("Authorization");
```

Sendo que o `HTTP` define a autenticação no seguinte formato:

> username:password

O servidor recebe a autenticação codificada em Base64 e no formato acima.
Por isso que no seu código, você teve que decodificar e quebrar a string no `:`:

```
int p = credentials.indexOf(":");

if(p > -1){
    username = credentials.substring(0,p);
    password = credentials.substring(p+1);
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error in decoding");
}
```